# accessing data in multiiindexed pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

Grouping by two columns and creating a DataFrame from the result gives me this multiindex table. I didn't manage to access an element from it as described in the documentation. The access fails with `KeyError: ('110166987', 'Direct Mail')`. What am I doing wrong here?

As a second question, can I somehow pivot this DataFrame so that the second index variable "Channel" becomes the columns?

Comment: What was your code that threw the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try:

```
df.loc[('110166987','Direct Mail')]
```

Comment: Is that consistent with http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#basic-indexing-on-axis-with-multiindex?